# summary of potential dll compatibility issues?

Tags: c++, c, windows, dll, compatibility

When an (unmanaged) Win32 program (or other DLL) calls an (unmanaged) Win32  DLL, my understanding is that there are a number of potential incompatibilities that could cause problems/crashes.

For instance, if program P calls DLL D, and P was compiled with Visual Studio 2013 to target Windows SDK version 8, and D was compiled to with Visual Studio 2017 to target Windows SDK version 10, my understanding is they will access different msvc runtime DLLs, which can cause problems. For instance, if D allocates memory with `new` and passes it back to P, and P tries to `delete` it, there is a crash because P and D are using two different runtimes, each maintaining their own heap.

Similarly, if P is built with run-time type information (RTTI) and D is not, my understanding is there can be crashing incompatibilities when, say, P allocates a class instance (to a type that each referenced in a common .h file) and passes it to D, because of differences in the virtual function table and/or in the padding between structure fields.

I'm trying to understand what other incompatibilities might exist. Ideally I'd like to find a complete list. Here are some possibilities that come to mind:

- Struct Member Alignment (similar to the RTTI issue)
- Use Multi-Byte Character Set vs. Use Unicode Character Set (could cause problems if string objects are passed/returned?)
- Omit (vs. do not omit) frame pointers (or perhaps this does *not* apply because the function call mechanism across programs/DLLs is different from the internal function call mechanism this flag relates to?)
- Enable (or disable) C++ Exceptions (exception handling works across a DLL call if they are both built with exceptions enabled and using the same runtime?)
- Others?

**EDIT**

I asked this question as a general curiosity, but also because I was having random heap corruption using a DLL in my program, and I was trying to figure out what could possibly be the problem.

My issue turned out to be that I was linking against an outdated DLL import library. I'm not exactly sure why the program started without error, and why it basically ran okay but with intermittent heap corruption. I believe it could only start without error if the new DLL offered a superset of the functionality provided by the old DLL import library. And then I'm not sure if the mechanism is a mismatch in C/C++ runtime libraries, or perhaps a change in a function's parameters without a breaking change in function signature?

In any event, I guess linking against an outdated DLL import library can be added to the list, although it's a less innocent mistake than the others mentioned.

Comment: MBCS vs. Unicode strings isn't going to be an issue on Windows if you follow the Win32 convention of using char*/string for MBCS and wchar*/wstring for Unicode (UTF-16.)

Comment: You can also have incompatibility in the very interface the DLL offers, say the system has version 1.0 of the DLL but the program was compiled against 2.0, you will need to install 2.0 for the program to work. On windows this was something the native side-by-side assembly system was supposed to help with but it turned out to be enough of a pain that it seems to have been nearly abandoned (the CRT is no longer a side-by-side assembly, for example).

Comment: @SoronelHaetir, thanks. Yeah, I was mostly thinking about hard-to-find, inconsistent crashes having to do with disagreements about memory, etc. (although my question didn't indicate that clearly). In your case the program would just outright fail to load, or crash right when you tried to GetProcAddress(), right?

Answer (score 2):

A very common mistake is using standard library stuff or other compiler implementation/version related features in dll-**interfaces**.
This will normally only work if both parties (dll and its user) use the same version of the compiler and even then there may be incompatibilities when one of them is build with DEBUG enabled and the other with NDEBUG.

Only use c-compatible types etc. in dll-interfaces.

Comment: To prove the point you're making, I have a DLL built with Visual Studio 2008, and it works correctly with applications compiled with VS 2017.  That is because the exported functions specify  `C` compatible or Windows API types as parameters.